# Warning: include: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Tags: magento-1.9, error, log, reward-points

I get this error in my `system` log but don't really understand what the problem is:

```
2017-12-05T14:22:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Points/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tabs/RewardPoints/History/Grid.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-12-05T14:22:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(Mage/Points/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tabs/RewardPoints/History/Grid.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
2017-12-05T14:22:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include(): Failed opening 'Mage/Points/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tabs/RewardPoints/History/Grid.php' for inclusion (include_path='/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/local:/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/community:/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/app/code/core:/domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/lib:.:/opt/php/php-5.4/lib/php')  in /domains/dev.domain.co.uk/http/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94
```

Here is the code from `Autoload.php` file:

```
82. public function autoload($class)
83. {
84.    if ($this->_collectClasses) {
85.        $this->_arrLoadedClasses[self::$_scope][] = $class;
86.    }
87.    if ($this->_isIncludePathDefined) {
88.        $classFile =  COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $class;
89.    } else {
90.        $classFile = str_replace(' ', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $class)));
91.    }
92.    $classFile.= '.php';
93.    //echo $classFile;die();
94.    return include $classFile;
95. }
```

Sometime customers do not receive their points for their purchase.

I am using Magento var. 1.9.2.4 and have a extension for "Reward Points" by `Magestore Extension`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that the file `Mage/Points/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tabs/RewardPoints/History/Grid.php` does not exist.

Most likely you forgot to upload it, or it was not included in the plugin.

Comment: Right. Also, the path starts from `Mage` does that mean the file should be somewhere in the core files? `app/code/core/Mage...`?

Comment: Technically that is possible, but it's more likely that it's placed in app/code/local/Mage. Try to find the module folder. It's probably in app/code/community or app/code/local. Perhaps somewhere in the module they refer to `Mage/Points` while they want to be referring to `Magestore/Points`. I can't tell without seeing the file structure.

Comment: I found the module in the `app/code/local/` but there is no directory called `Mage` or `Points` anywhere in this module... That's really strange :/

Comment: Is there a `Magestore/Points` folder? If so, that means that there's a typo somewhere in the code (I think probably in one of the .xml files of the module), where they typed `Mage/Points` instead of `Magestore/Points`

Comment: The thing is there is no `Magestore/Points` file path. I wrote to the Magestore team, maybe they can help me out with this one ;)